# Moments of inertia of composite area - xaxis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

struggling with this question. Got the a) ( y¯ = 3.79 in )but can't seem to get b)

[image]

a) Locate the centroid y¯ of the composite area.

b) Determine the moment of intertia of this area about the centroidal x′ axis.

my answer of 211 mm4 was wrong